# Can this be done without a HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I've created a simple game where 2 players enter inputs and the one with the bigger lead is declared the winner at the end of the game along with the winning margin. The first input you enter is the number of turns each player gets. In the output, I needed the player number and the margin mentioned. I was able to get it done but I want to know if this can be done without using a HashMap as I'm already using an arraylist as well. Can someone suggest a way for doing this?

```
    Scanner o = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int q = o.nextInt(), a1, b1, diff, max, w;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {   // q is the number of turns
        a1 = o.nextInt();   //first player input
        b1 = o.nextInt();   //second player input
        diff = (a1 > b1) ? a1 - b1 : b1 - a1;   //getting the difference
        w = (a1 > b1) ? 1 : 2;   //picking the winner for the turn
        map.put(diff, w);
        arrlist.add(diff);
    }

    max = arrlist.get(0); 
    for (int j = 0; j < arrlist.size(); j++) { 
        if (arrlist.get(j) > max)
            max = arrlist.get(j); 
    } 
    System.out.printf("%d %d", map.get(max), max );
```

Comment: You could use a running total - have two variables, one for each user.

Comment: Or create a new `class` which represents a 'difference' and a 'winner'.  `class Result { private int diff; private int winner; }`.  Then you can just track a single one of these, updating the local variable if the new diff is greater than the old one.

Comment: Just to make it easier for yourself and others in the future: You can get rid of most of the comments if you give your variables useful names instead! Just rename `q` to `numberOfTurns` and rename `a1` to `inputPlayer1` and `b1` to `inputPlayer2`. And calling an `ArrayList` `arrlist` is pretty pointless: name it to indicate what it *means*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:** Only 1 class solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner o = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input max match: ");
    int q = o.nextInt();
    int maxDiff = 0;
    int maxWinner = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {   // q is the number of turns
        System.out.println("Match " + String.valueOf(i + 1));
        System.out.print("1st player: ");
        int player1Input = o.nextInt();   //first player input
        System.out.print("2st player: ");
        int player2Input = o.nextInt();   //second player input
        int diff = Math.abs(player1Input - player2Input);   //getting the difference
        int winner = (player1Input > player2Input) ? 1 : 2;   //picking the winner for the turn

        if(diff > maxDiff) {
            maxDiff = diff;
            maxWinner = winner;
        }
    }

    if(maxWinner > 0) {
        System.out.printf("Winner player: %d Max diff: %d", maxWinner, maxDiff);
    }
}
```

**Old solution**: Add Match class to store diff + winner

```
public class StackOverflow_59349187 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner o = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input max match: ");
        int q = o.nextInt();

        List<Match> matches = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {   // q is the number of turns
            System.out.println("Match " + String.valueOf(i + 1));
            System.out.print("1st player: ");
            int player1Input = o.nextInt();   //first player input
            System.out.print("2st player: ");
            int player2Input = o.nextInt();   //second player input
            int diff = Math.abs(player1Input - player2Input);   //getting the difference
            int winner = (player1Input > player2Input) ? 1 : 2;   //picking the winner for the turn
            Match match = new Match(winner, diff);
            matches.add(match);
        }

        if(matches.size() > 0) {
            Match maxDiffMatch = matches.get(0);
            for (int j = 0; j < matches.size(); j++) {
                Match currentMatch = matches.get(j);
                int currentDiff = currentMatch.getDiff();
                int maxDiff = maxDiffMatch.getDiff();
                if (currentDiff > maxDiff) {
                    maxDiffMatch = currentMatch;
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("Winner player: %d Max diff: %d", maxDiffMatch.getPlayer(), maxDiffMatch.getDiff());
        }
    }

    static class Match {
        private final int player;
        private final int diff;

        public Match(int player, int diff) {
            this.player = player;
            this.diff = diff;
        }


        public int getPlayer() {
            return player;
        }

        public int getDiff() {
            return diff;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this one is fine, but I wanted to run it in just one class without having to create objects. Thanks

Comment: @wakanada I edited with only 1 class solution, take a look, hope it can help you!